# how can I wait the http request to finish in angular 8?

Tags: angular

this is my service

```
existWayBillByRsBillNumber(billNumber: string){
    return  this.http.get<boolean>(this.baseUrl + 'Common/ExistWayBillByRsBillNumber/'+billNumber);
  }
```

this is service call

```
this.commonService.existWayBillByRsBillNumber(this.buyerWaybill.waybillNumber).subscribe(
  response => {
    let exist = <Boolean>response;
    if (exist) {
      console.log(1);
      this.toastService.error('ზედდებული ნომრით ' + this.buyerWaybill.waybillNumber + " უკვე არსებობს!");
      return false;
    }
  }
);
console.log(2);
    }
  }
);
```

in console is printed 2 and after 1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOJan.png)

how i can wait a service response

Comment: You can't. Angular is all async so it will update everything is something is changed with change detection. if you want to catch the error do `,
  (error) => {` after the `responce => {}`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working as expected.

If we were to step through your code, it would go something like:

1. Call service
2. Make http request
3. Wait for response, return observable
4. console.log(2)
5. ...
6. HTTP response is returned
7. Execute callback of subscriber
8. console.log(1) [inside if condition]

So the fact is, you are already waiting for your service response - it's where you are checking the response and conditionally logging 1 to the console.

You have some issues with how you are making your request and handling the response, but your question effectively asks why 2 is logged before 1.

Edit:

This is a physical version of the steps above from the component's point of view:

```
console.log('1. Call service);

this.commonService
  .existWayBillByRsBillNumber(this.buyerWaybill.waybillNumber)
  .subscribe(response => {
    console.log('7. Execute callback of subscriber'); 

    if (response === true) {
      // handle true
    } else {
      // handle false
    }
  });

console.log(2);
```

Comment: Where does it say that? The http request is expected to return a `true` or a `false` according to the code

Comment: The question is about why 2 appears before 1 in the console, is it not?

Comment: `let exist = <Boolean>response;
    if (exist) {`

You still get an upvote cause it's right his question is unclear to.

Comment: How i can print first 1 then 2?

Comment: Obvious answer - move `console.log(2)` inside the subscribe. I suspect there's more to this question than you have given, as I'm not entirely sure what the problem is.

Comment: `validate() {    this.commonService.existWayBillByRsBillNumber(this.buyerWaybill.waybillNumber).subscribe(
      response => {
        let exist = <Boolean>response;
        if (exist) {
          this.toastService.error('ზედდებული ნომრით ' + this.buyerWaybill.waybillNumber + " უკვე არსებობს!");
          return false;
        }
      }
    );
    return true;
  }`     service in realy return true  and if statemant is true and must show error message, but validate method returning true(means no errors) and after service return true(means errors exist). sorry for my english

Comment: You don't return a value out of a subscribe. If you want to return a mutated value from an observable, you apply the map operator in a pipe. The body of the subscribe callback is the end of the line for an observable value. You perform your action in the subscribe.

Comment: I've updated the code in my answer to show where you handle the true/false response